# How to make new input display on a new line instead of replacing old input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to create a posting system. It sorta works but the problem is that everytime the user inputs new text, the old text gets replaced. I've been trying to solve this but have not had much luck. I'm using a combination of HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript I'm using CodePen so the skeleton and linking between files has been auto-coded for me.

HTML:

```
<form id="post" name="write">
<div class="textbox">
    <input class="postwriter" name="post" type="text" placeholder="What's on your mind?" id="myPost">
    <button id="Post" onclick= "return write_below(this); return resetIn();" value="submit">Post</button>
</div>

</form>
    <div class="posts" id="postDisplay">
        <p><span id='display'></span></p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #8ec7f9;
}

body {
    height: absolute;
    padding-top: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

#post {
    margin: auto;
}

#post .textbox {
    height: 100px;
}

#post .textbox .postwriter {
    width: 94.3%;
    height: 96%;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 95%, 1);
    font-size: 140%;
}

#post .textbox #Post {
    height: 100%;
    width: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #c78fff;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.posts {
    height: 100px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 110%;
}

.posts #display{
    margin: auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function write_below(form) {
    var input = document.forms.write.post.value;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = input;
    return false;
}
function resetIn(){
    document.getElementById("myPost");
    input.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the previous content instead of appending to it because of this line

```
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = input;
```

Change it to

```
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += input + "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text in another paragraph tag everytime the user hid post.
You can use the `+=` opperator to add more paragraph tags. You also don't want to nest paragraph tags, so we can get the `postDisplay` element instead.

```
function write_below(form) {
    var input = document.forms.write.post.value;
    document.getElementById('postDisplay').innerHTML += '<p>' + input + '</p>';
    return false;
}
function resetIn(){
    document.getElementById("myPost");
    input.reset();
}
```